# Bluetooth Android - Arduino App Error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I need your help!

First: I am from austria , so my english is not so good. So I apologize for the mistakes I will make!

This is my first project I try with Android Studio. I am a newbie in programming. I have not much skill in Arduino and Android program language, but I need it for my bachelor project, so I have to learn it!

I worked with a tutorial video, which was in spanish, so I have no clue what that guy was talking about, but I understood the code all in all.

My problem is, when I start the app on my phone, the first screen (paired devices) works fine. But when I press on the paired device...

This following error occurs :

> Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This
>   behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the
>   "Debugger" settings page. D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   ProgramCache.generateProgram: 103079215104 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: bachelor_projekt.bluetoothcontroller, PID: 11061
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {bachelor_projekt.bluetoothcontroller/bachelor_projekt.bluetoothcontroller.UserInterface}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth
>   address
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3506)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3546)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2795)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address
>                         at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.(BluetoothDevice.java:668)
>                         at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BluetoothAdapter.java:553)
>                         at bachelor_projekt.bluetoothcontroller.UserInterface.onResume(UserInterface.java:122)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1272)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6917)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3546) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2795) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11061 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

After that message, the app shuts down :

I divided my app in:

Bluetooth - for the bluetooth connection

Here is the code:

```
    package bachelor_projekt.bluetoothcontroller;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Bluetooth extends AppCompatActivity {



    // Cleaning of the Logcat (Systemlog)
    private static final String TAG = "Bluetooth";

    // Declaration of ListView
    ListView IdList;

    // String which will be sended to the main frame
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    // Declaration of the fields
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> myPairedDevicesArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //----------------------------
        VerificationBT();

        // Initialze the array which keeps the bluetooth devices
        myPairedDevicesArray=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);
        IdList = findViewById(R.id.idList);
        IdList.setAdapter(myPairedDevicesArray);
        IdList.setOnItemClickListener(myDeviceClickListener);

        // Get local default bluetooth adapter
        myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Includes the bluetooth member which is paired with the device
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices =myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();

        // Pair with an already in the array included device.
        if (pairedDevices.size()>0)
        {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices){
                myPairedDevicesArray.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }

    }

    // Configuration for the "on click" ability for the liste
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView av , View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

            // Detect the MAC-Adress of the device ( last 17 caracters)
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // 1 Try to connect if MAC adress is the same
            Intent i = new Intent(Bluetooth.this, UserInterface.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    };

    private void VerificationBT(){
        // Checks if the device has bluetooth and if it is activated

        myBluetooth=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(myBluetooth==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device doesn't have bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            if (myBluetooth.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth Avtivated...");
            } else{

                // Ask the user to activate bluetooth
                Intent enableBt = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBt,1);

            }
        }
    }
```

}

The second part is the user interface - Here should be the actual project which is just for start (3 Buttons, 1 for LED on, 1 for LED off, 1 for disconnect).

Here is the code:

```
package bachelor_projekt.bluetoothcontroller;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class UserInterface extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button IdLedON, IdLedOFF, IdDisconnect;
    TextView IdBuffer;
    //-------------------------------------------------

    Handler bluetoothIn;
    final int handlerState = 0;

    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder DataStringIN = new StringBuilder();
    private ConnectedThread MyConnection;

    // Special service - SPP UUID
    private static final UUID BTMODULE_UUID = UUID.fromString
            ("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00211300ACCD"); //805F9B34FB

    // String direction of the MAC
    private static String address = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_interface);

        // Connection between inferface and variables
        IdLedON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IdLedON);
        IdLedOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IdLedOFF);
        IdDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IdDisconnect);
        IdBuffer = findViewById(R.id.IdBuffer);

            bluetoothIn = new Handler(){
                public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){

                    if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                        String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                        DataStringIN.append(readMessage);

                    int endOfLineIndex = DataStringIN.indexOf("#");

                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                        String dataInPrint = DataStringIN.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                        IdBuffer.setText("Data: " + dataInPrint);
                        DataStringIN.delete(0, DataStringIN.length());
                   }
                }
            }
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        VerificationBT();

        IdLedON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v)  {
                MyConnection.write("1");
            }
        });

        IdLedOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyConnection.write("0");
            }
        });

        IdDisconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (btSocket != null)
                {
                    try {
                        btSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;}
                }
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException
    {
        // Creates a save Connection for the device
        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULE_UUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        // Receives MAC Adress Direction out of DeviceListActivity via intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // Receives MAC Adress Direction out of DeviceListActivity via EXTRA
        address = intent.getStringExtra(Bluetooth.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        // adjust MAC Adress
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);


        try
        {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error while Connection with device accured ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Creates a connection with bluetooth
        try
        {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e){
            try{
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2){}

        }
        MyConnection = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        MyConnection.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        try
        {
            // If you leave the application there can be no access to the bluetooth adapter
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2){}
    }

    // Check if bluetooth device is available and connect with it
    private void VerificationBT()
    {
        if (btAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device doesn't support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            Intent enableBt = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBt, 1);
        }

    }


    // class for making a connection
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread
    {
        private final InputStream myInStream;
        private final OutputStream myOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket)
        {
            InputStream tmpIn=null;
            OutputStream tmpOut=null;
            try
            {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        myInStream=tmpIn;
        myOutStream=tmpOut;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Device stays in the "try to connect" mode
            while(true) {
                try {
                    bytes = myInStream.read(buffer);
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(String input)
        {
            try{
                myOutStream.write(input.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // If it is not possible to send data
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if you need for information, just tell me.
Hopefully someone of you understands my problem and can help me :)

Best wishes
Semi

Comment: `address` is `null`. See `null is not a valid Bluetooth address at [...] bachelor_projekt.bluetoothcontroller.UserInterface.onResume(UserInterface.java:122)`. Why it is `null` is due to probably `Bluetooth.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS` not being present in the intent.

Comment: Hmm ok... And how do I make it present? Soory for that stupid question.... And Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an error in the code.

This error:
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity

Appeared way too many times which means and activity froze or crashed and then tried to restart but kept on failing so many times it just gave up in the end.

Also, it looks like your using a VM to test the code so try using it with a real device.

If you cant find out the problem try writing the code from the start again or run it through a bug interpreter.

Best of luck,
Paul!

Comment: Thank you Paul! I am testing it that way : I connect my phone to the PC and then press Run in Android studio and choose my phone as run device. My phone is an oukitel phone, do you think it could be that problem, that this is a Chinese phone? Best wishes semi

Comment: Yep fairly likely that. Try running your app in a vm.